# PolylineOptions + osmdroid

Tags: android, draw, osmdroid

I'm building an application which uses maps. I don't want to use any Play Services to serve maps (because that way everyone can use it), so I'm using `osmdroid` lib.

I need to pain an arc between 2 points, and the class `PolylineOptions` is not available without the Play Services.

Is there any way to do it, even using `osmbonuspack`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

osmdroid has a polyline class. The functions of PolylineOptions are in osmdroid's Polyline class. All you need to do is give it the points and add it to the map view.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it paints a straight line, not an arc